# Weird Behavior from ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an android test project with two classes:

1. `AdapterTestActivity` extends `ListActivity` -> http://pastebin.com/BreRSPj1
2. `MyAdapter` extends `ArrayAdapter` -> http://pastebin.com/YUK4CRQq

From `System.out.println()` in `MyAdapter` I get this printout:

```
05-22 16:43:03.942: I/System.out(17943): test 1
05-22 16:43:03.942: I/System.out(17943): test 2
05-22 16:43:03.950: I/System.out(17943): test 3
05-22 16:43:04.098: I/System.out(17943): test 1 
05-22 16:43:04.098: I/System.out(17943): test 2
05-22 16:43:04.098: I/System.out(17943): test 3
05-22 16:43:04.106: I/System.out(17943): test 1
05-22 16:43:04.106: I/System.out(17943): test 2
05-22 16:43:04.106: I/System.out(17943): test 3
```

but I expected something like:

```
test 1
test 2
test 3
```

Does anyone know why? - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a strange behavior, but it is  an implementation detail of the framework. There is no guarantee on which or order or how many time `getView()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

and for your 2nd question, you may need to add :

```
    _adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after adding your "test 4"